# Absolute complement of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a universal set $U$, I have two questions.

1) Is it guaranteed that any set $A$ is going to be a subset of $U$, because $U$ is the universal set?

2) In the context that $A$ *is* a subset of $U$, would it be valid to think of the absolute complement of $A$, as the logical negation of every element of $A$?

Comment: What is your definition of absolute complement?

Comment: @SeanRoberson U\A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In elementary set theory, once we talk about a universal set $U$, every set will be a subset of $U$. The complement of $A$ is the set of all elements that are in $U$ but not in $A$. We do not speak of the logical negation of every element of $A$, because the elements of $A$ are not logical statements. Rather, an element of $U$ is in the complement of $A$ if and only if it is not in $A$.

Comment: But would it be valid to think of U\A as "not A", even though neither A, nor its elements are necessarily logical statements?

Comment: @clathratus That really doesn't make a lot of sense. I get what you're trying to say, but equivocating those ideas, can lead to a lot of issues

Comment: @RushabhMehta so basically the absolute compliment of A in U would just be the same thing as the relative compliment of A in U, but what makes the difference between the two is the fact that U is the universal set, right?

Comment: @Don Thousand ~What kind of issues?